# Yii , show different date format in cgridview

Tags: php, yii

I had following cgridview in Yii application,
I want to change date format in value,

```
'columns'=>array(
        array(
                'name'=>'Date',
                'header'=>'Date',
                'value'=>'$data["work_date"]'
            ),
```

I want to show date in format dd-mm-yyyy currently it shows as yyyy-mm-dd.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this,

```
array(
    'name'=>'Date',
    'header'=>'Date',
    //'value'=>'date("d M Y",strtotime($data["work_date"]))'
    'value'=>'Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("d MMM y",strtotime($data->date))'
),
```

Comment: It would be better to use Yii provided tools. For this task exists [CDateFormatter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateFormatter#format-detail).

Comment: @sucotronic , i had currently use php core code for date display.
can't find the way to use CDateFormatter, can you plz give me an example code for this???
Thankx in advance.

Comment: @kiran: I have also not found any example that how to use CDateFormatter. I have tried dateFormatter, updated my code .

Comment: Great Kiran, that should work :) That method also gives you access to print dates in the actual locale locale loades in your application, and you can use [formatDateTime](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateFormatter#formatDateTime-detail) to print dates in a page.

Comment: @sucotronic, thankx for reply.
but i cant find how to use this function, the thing is in core documentation of yii, they do not provide simple example of related function.
plz can you give me an example of use this function to convert date.

Comment: @Kiran the code updated by Vibhaj should work without problems.

Comment: Note: For php 5.3+ better use anonymous functions instead expression as string.

Answer (score 5):

I guess there is more elegant way to format date (or anything else) than the one proposed in other answers. `CGridView` uses [formatter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#formatter-detail) property to specify application's [component to format values](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormatter). It's `format` by default.

So one should configure `format` component in application's configuration file like this:

```
'components' => array(
    ...
    'format' => array(
        'dateFormat' => 'd-m-Y'
    )
)
```

If `work_date` is already Unix timestamp then it's enough to describe the column in `CGridView` as follows:

```
array(
    'name' => 'work_date',
    'type' => 'date'
)
```

If `work_date` is like in the question then the column's array:

```
array(
    'name' => 'work_date',
    'type' => 'date',
    'value' => 'strtotime($data->work_date)'
)
```

If one has custom field to format that is not supported by [CFormatter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormatter) then it's easy to add your own [type](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn#type-detail) `custom` by extending `CFormatter`:

```
class MyFormatter extends CFormatter
{
    public function formatCustom($value)
    {
        // format $value parameter, i.e. make date conversion like in the question:
        return date("d-m-Y", strtotime($value));
    }
}
```

Then format component's configuration is:

```
'components' => array(
    ...
    'format' => array(
        'class' => 'MyFormatter'
    )
)
```

And the column is described like this:

```
array(
    'name' => 'work_date',
    'type' => 'custom'
)
```

This way there is no need to bother about [value](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn#value-detail) PHP expression each time you want to format field of the same type.

Comment: I agree. +1 for the Elegancy.

Comment: better solution, this one I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

There are (at least) two options:

(When using CGridView/CDetailView) you may want to format a date **string** (ie: mysql datetime field) instead of a timestamp.
You can use this:

```
array(
    'name' => 'startsOn',
    'format' => 'datetime',
    'value' => 'strtotime($data->startsOn)'
),
```

Or use this:

```
array(
    'name' => 'startsOn',
    'value' => 'Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("d MMM y", strtotime($data->startsOn))'
),
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Admin.php**

```
array(
        'name'=>'start_date',
        'header'=>'Date',
        'value'=>'date_format(date_create($data->start_date), "d-m-Y ")',
    ),
```

**For View.php**

```
array(
    'name'=>'Date',
    'value'=>date_format(date_create($model->order_date), "d-m-Y "),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest to create or alter the localization file of your target language, and refer it in your application instead of writing custom functions for it without centralizing the format. Please see https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n

```
// Refer our own locale file(s)
Yii::app()->setLocaleDataPath(Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.shared').'/i18n/data/');
```

For filtering on the localized date/datetime column in the gridview, please see my answer in a 'duplicate' question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53759001/3090890