# Yii: Saving date and time in DB

Tags: datetime, model, yii

I am having trouble saving the date in DB through Model. In my controller, if I dump the date in log that I receive from $_POST , I get the date in this format "10/Nov/2012 07:30". If I use:

```
$AccountAppointment->start_date=Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format($_POST['AccountAppointment']['start_date'], 'dd/M/yyyy HH:mm');
```

I get the error:

```
Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '10/NoGMT+5/2012 07:30' for column 'start_date'
```

Changing the format in dateFormatter to 'dd/M/yyyy HH:mm' or 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm' or 'dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm' throws the same error.

Db is MySQL 5.0, Yii version 1.1.12.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am almost stuck....thanks....

Answer (score 0):

I have used something like this in the past.  I used the CDateTimeParser to parse the date, and then format it the way you want.

```
echo Yii::app()->dateFormatter->formatDateTime(
    CDateTimeParser::parse($classified->create_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'
),'medium',null);
```

I assume you can do this:

```
echo Yii::app()->dateFormatter->formatDateTime(
    CDateTimeParser::parse($classified->create_date, 'dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm'
),'full',null);
```

or

```
echo Yii::app()->formatter->datetime(
    CDateTimeParser::parse($classified->create_date, 'dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm')
);
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for your feedback. Unfortunately none of the options you suggested worked. After wasting almost a day, I moved on with creating my own method to transform the date to required format. I have put my solution as answer in case it might help others. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong format. "Nov" corresponds to the pattern `MMM`, not `M` (that's the month as an integer without any leading zero).

Comment: I tried with all options, mentioned in my question also, kindly see text after the error statement in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any conversion to convert dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm date format to MySQL, so created my own method. This is just a workaround, as soon as I come up with a more elegant solution, I will update my answer. Following is the method that I created:

```
    public function returnDate($inputDate){
    //Input format of date is : dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm, example: 02/Feb/2012 18:20. The method converts the format to YYYY-MM-DD H:i which is compliant to MySQL 5.0 or above.
    $retval='';
    $dd=substr($inputDate, 0,2);
    $mm=substr($inputDate, 3,3);
    $yy=substr($inputDate,7,4);
    $tt=substr($inputDate,12,5);
    $month=0;
    switch($mm){
        case "Jan":
            $month='01';
            break;
        case "Feb":
            $month='02';
            break;
        case "Mar":
            $month='03';
            break;
        case "Apr":
            $month='04';
            break;
        case "May":
            $month='05';
            break;
        case "Jun":
            $month='06';
            break;
        case "Jul":
            $month='07';
            break;
        case "Aug":
            $month='08';
            break;
        case "Sep":
            $month='09';
            break;
        case "Oct":
            $month='10';
            break;
        case "Nov":
            $month='11';
            break;
        case "Dec":
            $month='12';
            break;
    }
    $retval=$yy.'-'.$month.'-'.$dd.' '.$tt;
    return $retval;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the format in your datepicker, by default it's yy-mm-dd

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't understand the format function. Please see below.

```
/**
 * Formats a date according to a customized pattern.
 * @param string $pattern the pattern (See {@link http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns})
 * @param mixed $time UNIX timestamp or a string in strtotime format
 * @return string formatted date time. Null if $time is null. (the null value check is available since Yii 1.1.11)
 */
public function format($pattern,$time){
----------------------
}
```

you need switch date format and time.
This is correct:

```
  $AccountAppointment->start_date=Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm' ,$_POST['AccountAppointment']['start_date']);
```

Hope I can help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built in CDateTimeParser:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', CDateTimeParser::parse($input, $format, array('second'=>0)))
```

Test:

```
$inputs = array('10/Nov/2012 07:30', '31/Jan/2012 23:59');
$format = 'dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm';
foreach($inputs as $input)
{
    echo $input . ' -> ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', CDateTimeParser::parse($input, $format, array('second'=>0)));
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Outputs:

```
10/Nov/2012 07:30 -> 2012-11-10 07:30:00
31/Jan/2012 23:59 -> 2012-01-31 23:59:00
```

In addition I wrote a wrapper function for above to take into account comparison operators, so you can use localized datetimes in the CGridView filters. Maybe it can be of any help. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53759001/3090890